# Program wipes serialized data after third compile

Tags: c#, serialization

**Problem**

Launch 1: Native launch, no problems, on exit, saves current state

Launch 2: Loads saved data, no problems, on exit saves current state

Launch 3: For some reason returns to native launch, where everything is in default position

---

**Code**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GenerateTestData(); //use method to create data upon load
DisplayEmployeeData(employees, supervisors); //use method to display data upon load
RedundancyCheck();
}



GenerateTestData Method 

public void GenerateTestData()
    {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Name1", MemberSkills.CPlus | MemberSkills.CSharp, false);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Name2", MemberSkills.CSharp | MemberSkills.Oracle | MemberSkills.CPlus, false);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Name3", MemberSkills.CSharp | MemberSkills.Javascript, false);
        Supervisor e4 = new Supervisor(MemberJob.Supervisor, "Name4", false);
        Supervisor e5 = new Supervisor(MemberJob.Supervisor, "Name5", false);
        employees.Add(e1);
        employees.Add(e2);
        employees.Add(e3);
        supervisors.Add(e4);
        supervisors.Add(e5);
    }
```

---

```
RedundancyCheck method

private void RedundancyCheck()
{
bool _success = false;
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
try
{
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open))
{
_success = true;
}
if (_success)
{
LoadData();
}
}
catch
{
if (!_success)
{
MessageBox.Show("There has been a problem with the main save, resorting to the backup copy!");
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("BackupMembers.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>)bFormatter.Deserialize(fs);
List<Supervisor> supervisors = (List<Supervisor>)bFormatter.Deserialize(fs);
ClearTable();
DisplayEmployeeData(employees, supervisors);
}
}
}
}
```

---

When the form closes it runs a SaveData method

```
private void SaveData()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            bFormatter.Serialize(fs, employees);
            bFormatter.Serialize(fs, supervisors);
        }
    }
```

---

So say for instance, Name1 was busy with a job, after I load it the second time, it displays fine, then when I load it the third time, it only displays what the TestData displays

---

**Update!**

It turns out that the SaveData file saves the default values on the second close.

Code from first close

```
Busy = true
EmployeeName = Name1
EmployeeWorkload = "Test"
ShiftsLeft = 2
```

---

Code from second close

```
Busy = false
EmployeeName = "Name1"
EmployeeWorkload = null
ShiftsLeft = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
```

`FileMode.OpenOrCreate` does not truncate the existing file, so you end up with an incorrect data.

Use `FileMode.Create` instead, which according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate.

**EDIT:** In your form you have the following fields definintions

```
private List<Employee> employees; //create a generic list of employees
private List<Supervisor> supervisors;
```

However, in some methods you use something like this

```
List<Employee> employees = ...
List<Supervisor> supervisors =
```

which creates a local variables, and your form fields stay default. To fix that, find the places inside the code where such locals are used and use the form variables instead like this

```
employees = ...
supervisors = ...
```

Comment: I have changed it to just `FileMode.Create` and still the same error

Comment: @DannyWatson Run it under the debugger and check what exceptions (if any) you are getting.

Comment: It's happening in the SaveData method, I crosschecked it after the first save, it saves as intended, the second save, I checked the .dat file and there was only the default values

Comment: Do it again. On the second run, put a breakpoint inside the `SaveData` and see what's in `employees` and `supervisors`. Another thing to check - does your `FILENAME` include a full path.

Comment: It has started throwing me some errors something to do with "end of stream encountered before parsing was completed" then it says that the .dat is in use

Comment: It turns out after only the second close it resorts back to the original default. I'll post an example in the O.P

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot help w/o you posting a full working example representing the problem that we can run and see what's going on.

Comment: @IvanStoev Please forgive any basic issues, this isn't the finished product

Comment: Np mate, we are here to help, not to judge. Let me take a look.